# How to select rows from a pandas DataFrame by specifying only the n-th index level?

Tags: pandas, select, multi-index, pandas-loc

I have a pandas DataFrame with a multi-level row index:

```
                 operators  license
                       sum      sum
City      Year
-----------------------------------       
New York  2020          44       A2
Chicago   2020          30       A2
Boston    2020          33       A1
New York  2021          48       A2
Chicago   2021          30       A2 
Boston    2021          41       A1
```

I can select rows with `.loc` by specifying only level 0 of the row index:

`df.loc[("Boston", )]`

But how do I select all rows where level 1 is 2020 without specifying level 0?
After some searching I found that `query` gives me the exact result I'm looking for:

`df.query("Year == 2020")`

Now I would like to know how to achieve this using `.loc`?

Comment: ```df.loc(axis=0)[:, 2020]```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm a bit puzzled as to why loc does not require the axis when I query for level 0...

Comment: I think another option would be ``df.loc[[:, '2020'], :]``. I think for level 0 it is just convenience not to ask for the axis (it is assumed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cross-section | MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#cross-section), you can use

```py
out = df.loc[(slice(None), 2020), :]

idx = pd.IndexSlice
out = df.loc[idx[:, 2020], :]

out = df.xs(2020, level='Year', drop_level=False)
out = df.xs(2020, level=1, drop_level=False)
```

```
print(out)

              operators license
                    sum     sum
City     Year
New York 2020        44      A2
Chicago  2020        30      A2
Boston   2020        33      A1
```

Comment: While I was perfectly happy with sammywemmys answer, this made me actually go back to the docs and I understood how the slice example works. ty!